# Is there a way to skip index in an array?

Tags: java

The input is supposed to be:

```
5
21,45
62,34
48,77
32,13
40,25
```

Where first line is the amount of coordinates. The rest of the lines are the coordinates.

The output is supposed to be:

```
20,12
63,78
```

Where the first line is the minimum X and Y values -1 and the second line is the maximum X and Y values +1.

```
    int drops;

    drops=scan1.nextInt();
    String[] array=new String[drops];
    
    int[] S=new int[drops*2];
    
    for(int x=0;x<drops;x++) {
        array[x]=scan2.nextLine();
        String[] NoComma=array[x].split(",");
        
        for(String s:NoComma) {
            System.out.println(s);
            S[x]=Integer.parseInt(s);
            System.out.println(S[x]);
        }
    }
```

So far I was able to take away the comma and convert the string values into int but I don't know how to continue from here.
I have an idea which is to skip index in the array so I can get a pattern similar to (stay, skip, stay, skip, stay, skip).
I'm feeling kind of lost. If you see this please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the first and second part of a coordinate pair are completely unrelated, why are you insisting on shoving them into a single array?

Stop doing that and this problem becomes much simpler. Have two arrays: The 'x' coords, and the 'y' coords. Then all you need to do is write code that 'finds the smallest number' and 'finds the largest number', which are trivial tasks (in fact, can be done in one go: Sort the inputs - now smallest is first item and largest is last, easy peasy), and adding 1 / subtracting 1 is even simpler than that.

`int[] x, y;` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a “which ones do I skip” (homework) problem. It’s a programming problem.

Since it’s homework, I want to rob you of the chance to learn by spoon feeding you code, but I will assist:

- at the top of your code, define 4 int variables called minX, maxX, minY and maxY
- set max’s to zero
- set min’s to a very large number
- loop over the lines - keep your outer loop
- for each line:

  - read `int x` from the scanner, then a comma, then `int y`, then
    nextLine
  - set minX to the minimum of x and minX
  - do similar for maxX, minY and maxY
- subtract 1 from min’s
- add 1 to Max’s
- print em

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code and somehow completed it. Also, you can check comments to see what happened there:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int drops;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter number of points:");
        drops=Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        int[][] array=new int[drops][2];
        System.out.println("OK, now enter coordinates per line( comma separated )");
        String[] rawCords;

        // Getting inputs
        for(int x=0;x<drops;x++) {

            rawCords = input.nextLine().split(",");
           
            array[x][0] = Integer.parseInt(rawCords[0]);
            array[x][1] = Integer.parseInt(rawCords[1]);

        }

        // Finding Max and Min
        int maxX = array[0][0],
            minX = array[0][0],
            maxY = array[0][1],
            minY = array[0][1];

        for(int i=0; i<drops; i++)
        {

            // Max
            if (array[i][0] > maxX)
                maxX = array[i][0];

            if (array[i][1] > maxY)
                maxY = array[i][1];

            // MIN
            if (array[i][0] < minX)
                minX = array[i][0];

            if (array[i][1] < minY)
                minY = array[i][1];
        }

        System.out.println("Min: " + (minX-1) + "," + (minY-1));
        System.out.println("Max: " + (maxX+1) + "," + (maxY+1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have them in an Array directly next to each other, then you can also work your way through them this way.

As you probably are a beginner, I'd suggest this way:

```java
int minX = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //everything is smaller than this,
int minY = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //the first one should just replace it
//when dealing with the max values, use the opposite: Integer.MIN_VALUE
//to make everything bigger than the initial value
        
for(int i=1;i<array.length;i+=2) { //start at 1 to avoid the count, "i+=2" to make it skip the Y coordinate entry
    minX = Math.min(minX, array[i]);
    minY = Math.min(minX, array[i+1]); //take it from the next one
}
```

This will work its way through the entries, while only targeting the X coordinate with the value of `i`. By looking forward into the Y value using `array[i+1]` you don't need to iterate over that seperately. Just keep track of the current X index you're at and add one, and you get the Y coordinate. Using this solution, just make sure to subtract one at the end to get your desired output.

If you want a quicker solution with some more advanced techniques, I can suggest you to look into Streams:

```java
int minX = IntStream.range(0, array.length-1) //create a sequential stream. "-1" because the first one is just the count
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0) //take every X coordinate by removing every odd element (keep the even ones)
        .map(i -> array[i+1]) //now place the real entries in there
        .min().orElse(0); //get the minimum value, if none return 0
//maxX works the same, just replace min() by max() in the last line
        
int minY = IntStream.range(0, array.length-1) //create a sequential stream. "-1" because the first one is just the count
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 1) //take every X coordinate by removing every even element
        .map(i -> array[i+2]) //now place the real entries in there. +2 to skip count, skip X and use Y coordinate
        .min().orElse(0); //get the minimum value, if none return 0
//maxY works the same, just replace min() by max() in the last line
```

This will create a list of indices first, to split the array into X and Y coordinates, then replace the indexes with the real values and finally the `min()` or `max()` operation returns the biggest/smallest value of that stream. The value of `orElse` will only be used, if the array is empty/has a length of 0.

Comment: Wow! I am amazed, this is amazing thank you so much